# C# Settings with verbatim string literal

Tags: c#

Perhaps I didn't see or understand any of the answers I read but I am having trouble using verbatim string literal (@) with `settings.Default.(mysetting)`. I am trying to do something like

```
Directory.GetFiles(@Setting.Default.(mysetting),"*.txt");
```

and cant seem to find the right syntax to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

The @ identifies  a string constant literal where back slashes should not be interpreted as escape signs. You can not use it in front of method invocations as you attempt here.

A valid assignment might be

```
 string path = @"c:\temp\example.txt";
```

Usually a \t would be interpreted as a tabulation character thus making the file reference illegal. It is exactly identical to

```
string path = "c:\\temp\\example.txt" ;
```

But bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

`@` verbatim string is used with string literals. So your code should be:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Setting.Default.(mysetting),@"*.txt");
```

because `"*.txt"` is the string literal in your code.

*(Although not related, but you can use `@` with variable names see [C# Variable Naming and the @ Symbol](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpAtNaming.aspx))*

Answer (score 1):

To use `@` as part of a verbatim string literal, the string literal must be right there - not just a property, method, etc. that returns a string.

```
string myStr = @"I'm verbatim, I contain a literal \n";
string myStr2 = "I'm not\nI have a newline";
string myStr3 = @myStr2; // still contains a newline, not a literal "\n"
```

Using `@` in front of an identifier allows you to use reserved keywords as identifiers. For example:

```
string @if = "hello!"; // valid
```

It also works on non-reserved words, where it has no real effect.

```
string @myVar = "hello!"; // valid
string newVar = myVar; // can be referred to either way
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing it, you still need to wrap the string within quotation marks.